# Oracle: Insert into a table type

Tags: oracle, types

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tabela is TABLE OF number;
```

I created this table and now I want to insert values so that I can return it in a function. How do I insert into this kind of table?

Comment: I'm creating a local variable in a stored function of "tabela" type, insert some numbers and then return it. So it's a PL/SQL block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/80f33/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tabela is TABLE OF number;

CREATE TABLE test ( val ) AS
          SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 6 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
-- In SQL
SELECT tabela( 1, 2, 4, 6 ) FROM DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/80f33/3/0)**:

```
| TABELA(1,2,4,6) |
|-----------------|
|         1,2,4,6 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
-- In SQL, getting value from a table
SELECT CAST( COLLECT( val ) AS tabela ) AS vals FROM test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/80f33/3/1)**:

```
|    VALS |
|---------|
| 1,2,4,6 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
-- In PL/SQL
DECLARE
  t tabela := tabela();
BEGIN
  t.EXTEND(4);
  t(1) := 1;
  t(2) := 2;
  t(3) := 4;
  t(4) := 6;
  -- Do stuff with t.
END;
```

**Query 4**:

```
-- In PL/SQL, getting values from a table:
DECLARE
  t tabela;
BEGIN
  SELECT val
  BULK COLLECT INTO t
  FROM test;
  -- Do stuff with t.
END;
```